# Detect if the landscape orientation of the device is "landscape right" or "landscape left"

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How to detect if the landscape orientation of the device is "landscape right" or "landscape left". Not sure if `OrientationBuilder` or `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation` can help us in this regard as they only provide the values '`landscape`' & '`portrait`'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by the help of [native_device_orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation) package. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:native_device_orientation/native_device_orientation.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool useSensor = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Native Orientation Example'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Center(child: Text('Sensor:')),
              Switch(value: useSensor, onChanged: (val) => setState(() => useSensor = val)),
            ],
          ),
          body: NativeDeviceOrientedWidget(
            landscape: (context) {
              return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: Landscape (Unknown Side)\n'));
            },
            landscapeLeft: (context) {
              return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: Landscape Left\n'));
            },
            landscapeRight: (context) {
              return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: Landscape Right\n'));
            },
            portrait: (context) {
              return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: Portrait (Unknown Side)\n'));
            },
            portraitUp: (context) {
              return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: Portrait Up\n'));
            },
            portraitDown: (context) {
              return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: Portrait Down\n'));
            },
            fallback: (context) {
              return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: Unknown\n'));
            },
            useSensor: useSensor,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Text('Sensor'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final orientation = await NativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator().orientation(useSensor: true);
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Native Orientation read: $orientation'),
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Text('UI'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final orientation = await NativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator().orientation(useSensor: false);
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Native Orientation read: $orientation'),
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `DeviceOrientation`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String orientation = '';
    if (DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft == true) {
      orientation = 'LandscapeLeft';
      print(orientation);
    }
 
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
         children: [
            Text(orientation) 
                    ]),
    );
  }
```